# Codes inside .getJSON() function doesn't fire

Tags: json, jquery

There lots of questions about getJSON but I couldn't find an answer to my problem. I have this simple code:

```
$.getJSON("ashx/GetVote.ashx?id=" + recordID, function (data) {
    $("#kg-VoteAvg-" + recordID).html(data.VoteAvg);
    $("#kg-VoteCount-" + recordID).html(data.VoteCount);
    alert("sth");
});
```

- In FireBug console, I see that a request happens.
- Parameter "id=2" is sent. That is recordID is 2.
- A valid JSON returns: `{VoteAvg:'1', VoteCount:'1'}`
- I also verified via FireBug console that `$("#kg-VoteAvg-" + 2).html(1);` works.

However, my code lines inside the function neither fires nor gives an error. Where do am I doing wrong? I can use .ajax() function but wondering why my alert or others in .getJSON() function doesn't work.

Comment: You said "doesn't fire", does it show the alert? (Nothing else is relevant it doesn't.) If it does, you may be interested to change it to: `alert("sth" + recordID)` and if that shows a fishy value, search SO for why.

Comment: Have you tried console.log(recordID) inside the callback function to see if that variable is accessible? It sounds like you have a variable scope problem.

Comment: Alert doesn't show up, as well as, the other two lines doesn't work. How can I get them work?

Comment: Neither console.log("sth") appear nor console.log(recordID) in the console.

Comment: $.getJSON() will silently fail if the returned JSON is formatted incorrectly and therefore won't execute the functions inside the callback. Check your GetVote script to make sure the returning values are correctly formatted (double quotes on string for example)

Comment: But FireBug recognizes the returning JSON as a valid JSON.

Comment: but jQuery may not think it's valid json. Remove all three lines and do a `console.log( data )` and see what the output is.

Comment: I thank you. Converting to a "valid" JSON solved the problem. Invalid ones continue working with .load() and .ajax() functions :)

Comment: I got it. $.ajax() function works with invalid JSON because the line `var result = eval('(' + data + ')');` inside $.ajax() function make it fit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JSON is not valid, you need to return

```
{"VoteAvg":1, "VoteCount":1}
```

http://json.org/ stipulates that JSON structures need to enclose their keys in double quotes.

Comment: You could also return `{"VoteAvg":"1", "VoteCount":"1"}` if you needed quotes for the values for some reason.

Comment: @Darcy, wouldn't that change the type of the value?

Comment: There is no difference. Moreover I am using `{VoteAvg:'1', VoteCount:'1'}` like format in other parts of my project in .ajax() function, they work. FireBug also recognizes it.

Comment: I missaw your code as `{'VoteAvg':1, 'VoteCount':1}`. There is difference with `{"VoteAvg":1, "VoteCount":1}`.

Comment: @Darcy, I did need the quotes for the values now, when I intended to write "no vote" instead of 0.